# Выбор подходящего ноутбука

Tags: ноутбук

Вопрос не совсем по программированию, а точнее - совсем не по программированию, однако размещение вопроса именно на этом Q&A объясняется тем, что нужно мнение людей из России. Непринадлежность вопроса к тематике сайта я компенсирую конкурсом на 50 баллов, который начну через 2 дня.
Итак, какой ноутбук нужен:

- Процессор: Core i5/i7;
- RAM: DDR3 - 4 Гб +;
- Встроенная видеокарта с ОЗУ 512 Мб +;
- HDD: 512 Гб +;
- Экран: матрица от 15,6 дюйма - Full HD.

Бюджет - от 32 до 50 тысяч рублей. Пожалуйста, пишите в ответах наилучший, по Вашему мнению, ответ - победитель получит от меня 50 баллов.

Comment: «совсем не по программированию» → закрыть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я использую Lenovo ThinkPad Edge 530. Вполне доволен, ОЗУ увеличил до 8ГБ. Интересовал изначально без windows и без дополнительной видюхи, т.к работаю под Линукс.
Встроенного Intel-овского видео обычно хватает на все: Вы ведь не собираетесь обрабатывать шейдеры или производить вычисления с плавающей запятой.
В текущей конфигурации он у меня прилично тянет одновременно 4 виртуалки под oracle vbox.

Answer (score 1):

Из производителей стоит смотреть только ASUS и Lenovo, так как собирают хорошо. i5 для ноутов не очень хорошо подходит в отличии от ПК, так что лучше i7 смотреть. ОЗУ меньше 8Gb вообще не стоит брать, в 2k18 4Gb не хватит, только если это не Linux, DDR 3 уже трудно найти, так что DDR 4.

По вышеописанным причинам рекомендую ноутбук `Lenovo IdeaPad 320-15IKBN 80XL0022RU`

Смотрел на "родном" сайте, но цена по курсу будет 45700р, [ссылка](https://catalog.onliner.by/notebook/lenovo/80sv00bbra).

**UPD:** [ссылка](https://market.yandex.by/product--noutbuk-lenovo-ideapad-320-15-intel/1730364335?lr=0&glfilter=5085104%3A12106116&glfilter=5085105%3A2500~2500&glfilter=5085115%3A12106353&glfilter=5085117%3A13904061&glfilter=5085119%3A13776093&glfilter=5085121%3A2048~2048&glfilter=5085125%3A1000~1000&glfilter=5085126%3A12106818&glfilter=5085139%3A1&glfilter=5085140%3A12106838&glfilter=5085141%3A1&glfilter=5085174%3A1&glfilter=6068613%3A12106928&glfilter=6069383%3A14290437&glfilter=10562516%3A8~8) на Яндекс Маркете

---

Если интересует ASUS, то вот 2 варианта:

- 2 ядка: ASUS VivoBook 15 X542UN-DM006
- 4 ядка: ASUS VivoBook 15 X542UN-DM056

Comment: Склонился бы все же к ThinkPade серии Edge: они гораздо дешевле "полных" Цинков. И i5 для ноута всегда 2-х ядерный, а 7-й уже дорог, и, возможно, избыточен. Огромный плюс Цинков: матовый экран. Хотя автор не обозначил цели для использования девайса.